# httpoison - response body showing garbled text instead of html

Tags: utf-8, elixir, httpoison

If I try:

```
url = "https://www.economist.com/news/finance-and-economics/21727073-economists-struggle-work-out-how-much-free-economy-comes-cost"    
{:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} = HTTPoison.get(url)
IO.binwrite body
```

I see garbled text (instead of html) in the console. But if I view source on the webpage, I see html there. What am I doing wrong?

PS: it works fine with a js http client (axios.js), not sure why it doesn't work with httpoison

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That URL returns the body in gzipped form and indicates this by sending the header `Content-Encoding: gzip`. `hackney`, the library HTTPoison is built on, does not automatically decode this. This feature [will likely be added at some point](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney/issues/155). Until then, you can decode the body yourself using the `:zlib` module if the `Content-Encoding` is `gzip`:

```
url = "https://www.economist.com/news/finance-and-economics/21727073-economists-struggle-work-out-how-much-free-economy-comes-cost"

{:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, headers: headers, body: body}} = HTTPoison.get(url)

gzip? = Enum.any?(headers, fn {name, value} ->
  # Headers are case-insensitive so we compare their lower case form.
  :hackney_bstr.to_lower(name) == "content-encoding" &&
    :hackney_bstr.to_lower(value) == "gzip"
end)

body = if gzip?, do: :zlib.gunzip(body), else: body

IO.write body
```